# setting a PictureFillSymbol via ArcObjects not wanted/allowed?

Tags: arcobjects, symbology

Have a problem in setting a **PictureFillSymbol** in polygon-layer-properties via ArcObjects. I just create the Bitmap not from file, it is "painted" in runtime. After loading the layer and setting the properties, the symbol in legend and map is correct shown, even colors. But in layer-properties-dialog the foregroundcolor could not be set, it is disabled/greyed. Also the checkbox for swap the colors. It is a **1bppindexed BMP**, just don't know, why ArcGIS this could not see.
 [image]

Here is a snippet from my code setting the symbol (Maybe somone has an idea?):

```
System.Drawing.Image img = CreateBitmapFromStipple(stipple);
// Farbpalette setzen
System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette cplr = img.Palette;
System.Drawing.Color colFG=System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255,col.Red,col.Green,col.Blue);
System.Drawing.Color colBG = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, bgcol.Red, bgcol.Green, bgcol.Blue);
cplr.Entries.SetValue(colFG, 0);
cplr.Entries.SetValue(colBG, 1);
img.Palette = cplr;

ISymbol fSymbol = new PictureFillSymbolClass();
(fSymbol as IPictureFillSymbol).Color = col;
(fSymbol as IPictureFillSymbol).BackgroundColor = bgcol;

stdole.IPictureDisp pd=VB6CompatibilityConverter.ImageToPictureDisp(img);
(fSymbol as IPictureFillSymbol).Picture = pd;

//(fSymbol as IPictureFillSymbol).BitmapTransparencyColor = bgcol;
(fSymbol as IPictureFillSymbol).SwapForeGroundBackGroundColor = textReader.GetAttribute("SwapForeGroundBackGroundColor").ToLower() == "true";
if (double.TryParse(textReader.GetAttribute("YScale").Replace('.', ','), out dHlp)) (fSymbol as IPictureFillSymbol).YScale = dHlp;
if (double.TryParse(textReader.GetAttribute("XScale").Replace('.', ','), out dHlp)) (fSymbol as IPictureFillSymbol).XScale = dHlp;
if (sOutLine != null) fSymbol.Outline = sOutLine;
```

> Added:

Maybe it is not allowed to set the Picture directly through Arcobjects?
In API reference I found out, picture is only a read-member, not write.

[image]

But however the set-Property is defined.

[image]

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the indexed format is locking in the colours (like a palette image) perhaps convert the image to just 1 bit per pixel without index (0.1) and the dialog will let you modify what 0 and 1 means as a RGB value.